# Parsing text files and sorting in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, parsing, sorting, text

I would like to write a Ruby program which can parse three separate text files, each containing different delimiters, then sort them according to certain criteria.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not clear what is the data format in your files, and what criteria you used to sort, so I am not able to provide you a accurate answer.

However, basically, you might need something like this:

```
File.open("file_name","r").read.split(",").sort_by {|x| x.length}
```

You:

- Opened a file using `File.open`.
- Read the whole file and got a string. You can also read the file line-by-line using the [`each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M002254) method.
- Split the string use `split`. The delimiter used is `,`.
- Use `sort_by` to sort them according to the criteria specified in the block.

Comment: How does "r" get used here? What does it represent? Also, I don't quite understand what {|x| w.length} does. If you could please break this down a little more for a Ruby n00b such as myself, it would me much appreciated.

Comment: "r" represents that the file is being opened in "Read" mode. Also, w.lenth looks like a type. It should really be x.length.
`{|x| x.length}` is a block passed to `sort_by` method. It makes the sort_by method sort by the length of each of the "split" words. Here, the word separator used is comma (,) in the `split` method.

Answer (score 2):

[Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003120) will allow you to sort an array (or other enumerable object) with a specific comparison function.

Answer (score 0):

If by "text files with delimiters" you mean CSV files (character seperated values), then you can use the [`csv` library](http://Ruby-Doc.Org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/), which is part of the standard library, to parse them. CSV gives you objects that look and feel like Ruby `Hash`es and `Array`s, so you can use all the standard Ruby methods for sorting, filtering and iterating, including the aforementioned `Enumerable#sort_by`.